# I am unable to update values in two attributes which is mapped by ModelMap in Spring JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0

I am working on an web application based on Spring JPA Hibernate which contains student health record. Here is the entity named "HealthRecord.java" which contains two lists named "Doctor Contact Numbers" and "Disease". When i update the student health record using ModelMap and StudentDTO then all records updates except "DoctorContactNumbers" and "Disease"; these records remained same as previously stored in my db.

Here is my code:

```
**HEALTH RECORD.java**
package com.makabu.sis.domain.student;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Version;

import com.makabu.sis.domain.BloodGroup;

@Entity
public class HealthRecord {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Version
private Long version;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private BloodGroup bloodGroup;
private String weight;
private String height;
private String hearing;
private String eyesight;
private String doctorName;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(name = "doctor_number")
private List<String> doctorContactNumbers;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(name = "disease")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private List<Disease> diseases;

@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String allergies;

@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String psychologicalDisorders;

@OneToOne(optional = false)
private Student student;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Long getVersion() {
    return version;
}

public void setVersion(Long version) {
    this.version = version;
}

public Student getStudent() {
    return student;
}

public void setStudent(Student student) {
    this.student = student;
}

public BloodGroup getBloodGroup() {
    return bloodGroup;
}

public void setBloodGroup(BloodGroup bloodGroup) {
    this.bloodGroup = bloodGroup;
}

public String getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public void setWeight(String weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}

public String getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(String height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public String getHearing() {
    return hearing;
}

public void setHearing(String hearing) {
    this.hearing = hearing;
}

public String getEyesight() {
    return eyesight;
}

public void setEyesight(String eyesight) {
    this.eyesight = eyesight;
}

public String getDoctorName() {
    return doctorName;
}

public void setDoctorName(String doctorName) {
    this.doctorName = doctorName;
}

public List<String> getDoctorContactNumbers() {
    return doctorContactNumbers;
}

public void setDoctorContactNumbers(List<String> doctorContactNumbers) {
    this.doctorContactNumbers = doctorContactNumbers;
}

public List<Disease> getDiseases() {
    return diseases;
}

public void setDiseases(List<Disease> diseases) {
    this.diseases = diseases;
}

public String getAllergies() {
    return allergies;
}

public void setAllergies(String allergies) {
    this.allergies = allergies;
}

public String getPsychologicalDisorders() {
    return psychologicalDisorders;
}

public void setPsychologicalDisorders(String psychologicalDisorders) {
    this.psychologicalDisorders = psychologicalDisorders;
}
}
```

Here is "**STUDENT DTO.java**"

```
package com.makabu.sis.dto;

import java.util.List;

import com.makabu.sis.domain.imagelib.FileLibrary;
import com.makabu.sis.domain.student.Student;
import com.makabu.sis.util.Wizard;

public class StudentDTO {
private Student student;
private List<Long> subjectsIds;
private Long batchId;
private Long academicYearId;

private String dateOfBirth;

private ImageLibraryDTO photograph;// = new ImageLibraryDTO();
private ImageLibraryDTO bForm;// = new ImageLibraryDTO();
private ImageLibraryDTO leavingCertificate;// = new ImageLibraryDTO();
private ImageLibraryDTO transcripts;// = new ImageLibraryDTO();

private FileLibrary uploadedPhotograph;
private FileLibrary uploadedBForm;
private FileLibrary uploadedLeavingCertificate;
private List<FileLibrary> uploadedTranscripts;

private List<StudentParentDTO> studentParent;

private Boolean childLastSchoolInfo;

private Boolean secondParent;

private Wizard step;

private Long siblingId;

public ImageLibraryDTO getPhotograph() {
    return photograph;
}

public void setPhotograph(ImageLibraryDTO photograph) {
    this.photograph = photograph;
}

public ImageLibraryDTO getbForm() {
    return bForm;
}

public void setbForm(ImageLibraryDTO bForm) {
    this.bForm = bForm;
}

public ImageLibraryDTO getLeavingCertificate() {
    return leavingCertificate;
}

public void setLeavingCertificate(ImageLibraryDTO leavingCertificate) {
    this.leavingCertificate = leavingCertificate;
}

public ImageLibraryDTO getTranscripts() {
    return transcripts;
}

public void setTranscripts(ImageLibraryDTO transcripts) {
    this.transcripts = transcripts;
}

public Student getStudent() {
    return student;
}

public void setStudent(Student student) {
    this.student = student;
}

public List<Long> getSubjectsIds() {
    return subjectsIds;
}

public void setSubjectsIds(List<Long> subjectsIds) {
    this.subjectsIds = subjectsIds;
}

public Long getBatchId() {
    return batchId;
}

public void setBatchId(Long batchId) {
    this.batchId = batchId;
}

public Long getAcademicYearId() {
    return academicYearId;
}

public void setAcademicYearId(Long academicYearId) {
    this.academicYearId = academicYearId;
}

public List<StudentParentDTO> getStudentParent() {
    return studentParent;
}

public void setStudentParent(List<StudentParentDTO> studentParent) {
    this.studentParent = studentParent;
}

public Boolean getSecondParent() {
    return secondParent;
}

public void setSecondParent(Boolean secondParent) {
    this.secondParent = secondParent;
}

public Wizard getStep() {
    return step;
}

public void setStep(Wizard step) {
    this.step = step;
}

public String getDateOfBirth() {
    return dateOfBirth;
}

public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}

public Boolean getChildLastSchoolInfo() {
    return childLastSchoolInfo;
}

public void setChildLastSchoolInfo(Boolean childLastSchoolInfo) {
    this.childLastSchoolInfo = childLastSchoolInfo;
}

public FileLibrary getUploadedPhotograph() {
    return uploadedPhotograph;
}

public void setUploadedPhotograph(FileLibrary uploadedPhotograph) {
    this.uploadedPhotograph = uploadedPhotograph;
}

public FileLibrary getUploadedBForm() {
    return uploadedBForm;
}

public void setUploadedBForm(FileLibrary uploadedBForm) {
    this.uploadedBForm = uploadedBForm;
}

public FileLibrary getUploadedLeavingCertificate() {
    return uploadedLeavingCertificate;
}

public void setUploadedLeavingCertificate(
        FileLibrary uploadedLeavingCertificate) {
    this.uploadedLeavingCertificate = uploadedLeavingCertificate;
}

public List<FileLibrary> getUploadedTranscripts() {
    return uploadedTranscripts;
}

public void setUploadedTranscripts(List<FileLibrary> uploadedTranscripts) {
    this.uploadedTranscripts = uploadedTranscripts;
}

public Long getSiblingId() {
    return siblingId;
}

public void setSiblingId(Long siblingId) {
    this.siblingId = siblingId;
}
}
```

Here is "**UpdateStudentController.java**"

```
private void bindModelMap(ModelMap modelMap, StudentDTO studentDTO) {
    modelMap.addAttribute("genderList", Gender.values());
    modelMap.addAttribute("academicYearList",
            academicYearService.readAllAcademicYears());
    modelMap.addAttribute("bloodGroups", BloodGroup.values());
    modelMap.addAttribute("diseases", Disease.values());

    modelMap.addAttribute("referenced", Referenced.values());

    modelMap.addAttribute("employeeList", employeeDao.readAllEmployees());
    modelMap.addAttribute("parentAssociation", ParentAssociation.values());

    HealthRecord healthRecord = studentService.readHealthRecordById(studentDTO.getStudent().getHealthRecord().getId());

    if(healthRecord != null){

        modelMap.addAttribute("healthRecord", studentDTO.getStudent().getHealthRecord());

        healthRecord.setDiseases(studentDTO.getStudent().getHealthRecord().getDiseases());
        healthRecord.setDoctorContactNumbers(studentDTO.getStudent().getHealthRecord().getDoctorContactNumbers());

        healthRecord.setAllergies(studentDTO.getStudent().getHealthRecord().getAllergies());
        healthRecord.setBloodGroup(studentDTO.getStudent().getHealthRecord().getBloodGroup());
        healthRecord.setDoctorName(studentDTO.getStudent().getHealthRecord().getDoctorName());
        healthRecord.setEyesight(studentDTO.getStudent().getHealthRecord().getEyesight());
        healthRecord.setHearing(studentDTO.getStudent().getHealthRecord().getHearing());
        healthRecord.setHeight(studentDTO.getStudent().getHealthRecord().getHeight());
        healthRecord.setWeight(studentDTO.getStudent().getHealthRecord().getWeight());
        healthRecord.setPsychologicalDisorders(studentDTO.getStudent().getHealthRecord().getPsychologicalDisorders());

        studentDTO.getStudent().setHealthRecord(healthRecord);

    //  healthRecord.setStudent(student);

    //  studentDTO.setStudent(student);
    } else{
        healthRecord = new HealthRecord();
        studentDTO.getStudent().setHealthRecord(healthRecord);
    }
    }
```

Here is my update method:

```
@Override
public Student updateStudent(Student student) {
    return merge(student);
}
```

Please let me know my mistake and give me the solution. Thanks in advance.
I need healthy solution; because I am working on a live project.

Comment: Where's your update statement?

Comment: There is no issue in update method. It updates my all other info correctly but it dont update new values of "DoctorContactNumbers" and "Disease".  The issue is that both these lists are binded by modelmap and it doesnot allow me to update new record.

Comment: It does not give any error and save previous record against these lists.

I am getting issue in these lines below: 

healthRecord.setDiseases(studentDTO.getStudent().getHealthRecord().getDiseases());
   healthRecord.setDoctorContactNumbers(studentDTO.getStudent().getHealthRecord().getDoctorContactNumbers());

Comment: Have you tried sysout the following statements, `studentDTO.getStudent().getHealthRecord().getDiseases()‌` and `studentDTO.getStudent().getHealthRecord(‌​).getDoctorContactNumbers()` , is it returning any data or just null?

Comment: yes i tried it and it returns me the new data i entered.

The problem is that i am unable to update this data.

Comment: that maybe due to kind of Cascade in hibernate mapping for those child objects in the parent class. Try declaring Cascade to "All" or "Save-Update" in hibernate mapping annotation for those respective child object mappings.

Comment: @user1354678 Please check my HealthRecord Entity; it defines no any cascading type. I am not allowed to change in model. As my team lead asked me that model is finalized and accurate; it dont needs any modification.

Comment: Let me get straight, I can't figure out without enough information, you're finally updating a Student object but I don't see any Student Class in your question. Even if I can't help, I'm sure others will help if you've provided enough information.

Comment: Actually Student is the main entity which uses StudentDTO (with same attributes + getters and setters) to add, update and delete records of student.

Comment: If you can come on skype so then I may sure my main code ..